# Php, Mysql Match in Set multiple values

Tags: php, mysql, search

How can I perform this type of search?

Here is my table:

```
Name                    Category
---------------------------------
Company1                food,services
Company2                garden,gifts,services
Company3                other,auto
```

and here is the query:

```
$search = $_GET['search'];
"SELECT * FROM companies WHERE category IN ('$search')";
```

The above search variable looks like mydomain.com?search=garden,services

The idea is to get all relevant rows if any of the matching keywords are present within Category field.

Comment: Take advantage of what the database offers, and store 1 term per row.

Comment: And yes, I'd agree that searching for multiple words as one item isn't ideal.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest SQL search is probably a LIKE search:

```
SELECT * from companies where category LIKE ("%$search%");
```

You can also do a REGEXP search:

```
SELECT * from companies where category REGEXP ("$search");
```

What many have ended up doing, though, is [fulltext](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-fulltext-index.html) searching.  You can configure MySQL to do this, or perhaps you'll want to try a solution like [SphinxSearch](http://sphinxsearch.com/).

Comment: Thanks but LIKE and REGEXP does not work, it always returns one record. If the search string is . services, other, I should get all three records, but instead only the first matching record is returned (Company 1)

Comment: That's abnormal.  Show your data.